# C++ function won't work with my two variables

Tags: c++, function

My code is supposed to ask someone for their first and last name separately, but my function is skipping the last name for some reason. How can I fix this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void read_name(char first[], char last[]);

void read_name(char first[], char last[])
{
    cout << "your name is " << first <<  last << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char firstt[15], lastt[15];
    read_name(firstt, lastt);
    cout << "enter first name" << endl;
    cin.get(firstt, 15, '\n');
    cout << "enter last name" << endl;
    cin.get(lastt, 15, '\n');

    read_name(firstt, lastt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Please post real code.

Comment: In main() you must define firstt and lastt before you can use it.

Comment: I defined firstt and lastt its still having the problem of skipping lastt when it compiles

Comment: You should move your `cin` statements into your `read_name` function.  If you used `std::string`, you could pass a `std::string` variable by reference and not worry about buffer overflows.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that member function `get` does not extract the new line character from the stream. So the next call of get reads nothing. Add a call of function ignore. For example

```
cout << "enter first name" << endl;
cin.get(firstt, 15, '\n'); 
cout << "enter last name" << endl;
cin.ignore();
cin.get(lastt, 15, '\n');
```

Also remove the first call of read_name because it has no any sense.

EDIT: I think you forgot to write

```
char first[15];
char last[15];
```

in your code example

Answer (score 1):

Vlad's answer is correct, but I wanted to provide an alternative.  You can also use `cin.getline()`.  This avoids having to call `cin.ignore()`.

```
cout << "enter first name" << endl;
cin.getline(firstt, 15); 
cout << "enter last name" << endl;
cin.getline(lastt, 15);
```

If you are worried about your users entering more than 15 characters at a time, you will need to add something like `cin.ignore(200, '\n')` after the first getline.

Answer (score 1):

Vlad and user3624257 have correct answers, but you should be using `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.

For example, handling buffer overruns.  What happens when a user enters a 20 letter string and you only allocated 15?
The `std::string` handles dynamic memory reallocation for you.

Also, you have worry about the terminating nul ('\0') character at the end of the line.

The `std::string` class has more useful member functions, such as `find_first_not_of`.